# Is event blur fireing by closing browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, blur

I have a small question.

I want to check inputs after the blur event. A ajax-request should start an count something. So I don't want to check if the user is doing something in the input only after they finished doing something, but what if they focus the input and the users next click is to close the browser window?

Is the blur event is still firing?

Comment: No, but the onclose event is firing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose

Comment: thanks, just wanted to know the blur event. :)